# How to use onActivityResult in Android

Tags: java, android

In my application I want to use **onActivityResult** in Activity and for this I write below codes.
But after call **onActivityResult** show me logs for **2 times** and show error result!
I used **MediaProjectionManager** and click on Allow permission, but why show cancel request code?
**My codes :**

```
    private CountDownTimer reverseTimer() {
        return countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2 * 1000, 1000) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int second = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                if (millisUntilFinished < 1100) {
                    onFinish();
                } else {
                    txtTesterCounter.setText(App.enToFa(second + ""));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
                Intent permissionIntent = mediaProjectionManager != null ? mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent() : null;
                startActivityForResult(permissionIntent, ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
                Log.e("ResultLog", "Request : " + ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //The user has denied permission for screen mirroring. Let's notify the user
        Log.e("ResultLog", "Request : " + resultCode + "---" + "Request : " + requestCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Access failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
}
```

**Logcat messages :**

```
2022-09-21 19:16:46.948 10083-10083/com.myapp E/ResultLog: Request : 1003
2022-09-21 19:16:47.908 10083-10083/com.myapp E/ResultLog: Request : 1003
2022-09-21 19:16:48.276 10083-10083/com.myapp E/ResultLog: Request : 0---Request : 1003
2022-09-21 19:16:48.349 10083-10083/com.myapp E/ResultLog: Request : -1---Request : 1003
```

Why call log codes 2 times and not allow permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `onFinish()` yourself.

It will automatically be called when... all has finished..

Answer (score 0):

its calling it first time when your condition is returning true and second time when its actually finished by itself , Means the timer is not being stopped or cancelled when your condition is true, to make it call once you need to stop the timer under the `onFinish();` method there is method called `cancel()` to stop the timer try with your object name in your case its `countDownTimer` so it should look something like `countDownTimer.cancel()` under the `onFinish()`

let me know if that solved the issue.